# How to merge two columns c1 and c2 of two dataframes df1 and df2 respectively in column c1 of df1 ? c1 and c2 are dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns C1 and C2 in datafarmes df1 and df2 respectively. I wish to merge C1 and C2 into one in df1(or df2) such that the values in dictionary add up if the keys are same and append value in the dictionary if the key don't doesn't exist already.

[image: two dataframes]

The output that I want is:
I want to aggregate everything at le_id level, run_seq = 'latest' for every row and merge two dictionaries i.e add values if the key exist else append to the existing dict. The output should be a dataframe. Something like this , not exactly the same result

Edit :
The code that creates this dataframe is :

```
import pandas  as pd
data = {'le_id' : [101]*4 + [102]*4 + [103]*3 + [104]*5 + [101],
       'run_seq' : [31]*11 + [32]*6,
       'cp_id' : [201, 201, 201, 201, 203, 204, 205, 205, 206, 208, 209, 202, 201, 204, 205, 208, 208],
       'cp_name' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'H'],
       'products' : ['U', 'U', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'U', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X','U', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z', 'U'],
       'tran_amnt' : [10203, 13789, 74378, 47833, 40237, 93732, 63738, 42563, 92822, 11276, 63633, 99292, 27892, 82727, 32442, 55622, 43535],
       'currency' : ['USD', 'YEN', 'USD', 'SGD', 'USD', 'INR', 'INR', 'SGD', 'USD', 'INR', 'SGD', 'SGD', 'SGD', 'SGD', 'INR', 'INR', 'INR']}
data_gb = data.groupby(['le_id', 'cp_id', 'run_seq', 'products', 'currency']).sum()
data_gb.reset_index(inplace = True)
data_gb
```

I then do this and the result is the above two dataframes :

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
from pprint import pprint
def add_current_counterparty_interaction(df):  
    df_this = df.copy()    
    current_interaction_dict = {}

    for cp_id in df_this.cp_id.values:
        prod_curr_dict = {}
        rows_to_filter = df_this.cp_id==cp_id
        for prod in df_this.loc[rows_to_filter, 'products'].values: #product repeating
            curr_amount_dict = {}
            rows_to_filter_prod = rows_to_filter & (df_this.products == prod)
            for curr in df_this.loc[rows_to_filter,'currency'].values:
                rows_to_filter_curr = rows_to_filter_prod & (df_this.currency == curr)
                if rows_to_filter_curr.any():
                    #print(df_this[rows_to_filter_curr].tran_amnt)
                    this_tx_amt = df_this[rows_to_filter_curr].tran_amnt.values
                    curr_amount_dict[curr] = this_tx_amt
            if len(curr_amount_dict):
                prod_curr_dict[prod] = curr_amount_dict
        if len(prod_curr_dict):
            current_interaction_dict[cp_id] = prod_curr_dict
    pprint(current_interaction_dict)
    return current_interaction_dict


def process_counterparty_journey(df, rs):
    df_this = df[df["run_seq"]==rs].copy()
    #add_current_counterparty_interaction(df_this, 101)
    df_op = df_this.groupby(["le_id", "run_seq"]).apply(lambda x: add_current_counterparty_interaction(x)).reset_index()
    #print(df.head())
    #print(df_this)
    #pprint(df_op[0].values[0])
    pprint(df_op)
    return df_op
a = process_counterparty_journey(data_gb, 31)
b = process_counterparty_journey(data_gb, 32)
```

The resulting dataframe a and b are the two dataframes printed above. 
rs is run_seq i.e 31 and 32.

The fucntion that I want should take a and b (dataframes) as arguments and should return a dataframe. look at the other question that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498363/how-can-i-merge-merge-two-dictionries-while-performing-addition-operation-on-sam) . The le_id should be unique in le_id column.

Comment: can you please show us your existing code and a sample of your input, as well as desired output. In other words, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). , its always better to create a code which creates / replicates your dataframes ,you may want to take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @anky_91 I just made some changes according to your suggestion. Thank you.